# How can i judge whether a user has refunded from auto-renewable subscription or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am implementing an auto-renewable subscription in my app.

Currently, to check if the user have an active subscription, I examine all the records in latest_receipt_info array from the response JSON returned from the Apple's /verifyReceipt service, i am wondering what will happen if a user ask for refund? Can he still use the subscription? If so how can i judge he is a refunded user?